# Shell expansions are not performed when running a command with `subprocess.call' with `shell=True'

Tags: python, linux, makefile, subprocess, os.system

I am trying to build some files using python but it is executing it in a wrong manner.

I have tried to build some files in linux.
when i use "`make ./package/feeds/proj/{clean,compile} V=s`" command in the terminal, it is working properly, but when i try to run it with a python script, using the command "`p = subprocess.call(r'/usr/bin/make package/feeds/proj/{clean,compile} V=s',shell = True))`", it is behaving differently.

Logs :

when run in terminal :

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/local/mnt/workspace/rubaeshk/unused2/qsdk'
make[2]: Entering directory '/local/mnt/workspace/rubaeshk/unused2/qsdk/package/feeds/whc/qca-whc-crash-log'
rm -f /local/mnt/workspace/rubaeshk/unused2/qsdk/bin/ipq/packages/whc/qca-whc-crash-log_*
..(log continued until successfully built)
```

when run through python script :

```
WARNING: your configuration is out of sync. Please run make menuconfig, oldconfig or defconfig!
make[1]: Entering directory '/local/mnt/workspace/rubaeshk/unused2/qsdk'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'package/feeds/whc/qca-whc-crash-log/{clean,compile}'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/local/mnt/workspace/rubaeshk/unused2/qsdk'
/local/mnt/workspace/rubaeshk/unused2/qsdk/include/toplevel.mk:186: recipe for target 'package/feeds/whc/qca-whc-crash-log/{clean,compile}' failed
make: *** [package/feeds/whc/qca-whc-crash-log/{clean,compile}] Error 2
```

Could someone see where it went wrong..

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [`subprocess.Popen` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#subprocess.Popen) (`subprocess.call` delegates to `Popen` like all other convenience functions), `subprocess.call('command', shell=True)` in Unix is equivalent to running the *argv*:

```
['/bin/sh', '-c', 'command']
```

And `sh` does not support brace expansion (this is the official name for the `{a,b}` syntax).

To run the command with `bash` instead, you need to override the shell executable used with the `executable` parameter:

```
p = subprocess.call('command', shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

Example:

```
$ python -c 'import subprocess; subprocess.call("echo /usr/{lib,bin}", shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")'
/usr/lib /usr/bin
```

---

Note however that using `shell=True` is discouraged because it's inherently platform-specific, depends on local shell and its settings, and may be a bug or security vulnerability if you use untrusted input. Better construct the command line by hand and pass the resulting *argv.*

Answer (score 1):

Brace expansion is not part of the standard shell; it's an add-on feature provided by some shells (like bash) in addition to POSIX.  When you run subprocess.call in Python it's probably using `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`.

So, write it out: `package/feeds/whc/qca-whc-crash-log/clean package/feeds/whc/qca-whc-crash-log/compile`